# Different linestyles for the same contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a contour plot, which for a fixed value there are two separate contours. I want to distinguish these two contours from each other, for example one with dashed one and one with simple line. I'm using python and Matplotlib.

Thanks!

In the figure below, I want one of the red contours ( corresponding to value 1) to be dashed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3a40.png)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation of `contour()`, you find that you can use a list of linestyles like you can use a list of colors.

See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html).

```
linestyles{None, 'solid', 'dashed', 'dashdot', 'dotted'}, optional

    Only applies to contour.

    If linestyles is None, the default is 'solid' unless the lines are monochrome. In that case, negative contours will take their linestyle from rcParams["contour.negative_linestyle"] (default: 'dashed') setting.

    linestyles can also be an iterable of the above strings specifying a set of linestyles to be used. If this iterable is shorter than the number of contour levels it will be repeated as necessary.
```

Comment: This applies on contours for a particular level. My question was that, when we have two contours corresponding to a level, how to make one of them different from the other.

Comment: I am not sure if this possible in general. While you could change the linestyle of each level, there is only one line in the `plt.contour().collections` object for each level, even if the line appears twice, as in your case.